# Slider UI in WordPress Customizer

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, uislider

I have the problem with getting value of Slider UI in the WordPress customizer.

Here is the class of control:

```
class styler_slider extends WP_Customize_Control{

        public $type = 'slider';

        public function enqueue(){
            wp_enqueue_script('customizer-slider', plugins_url('js/slider-ui.js', __FILE__), array('jquery-ui-slider'), '1.0', true);
            wp_register_style('customizer-slider-styles', plugins_url('css/slider-ui.min.css', __FILE__));  
            wp_enqueue_style('customizer-slider-styles');
        }

        public function render_content(){
            ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html($this->label); ?></span>
                <div class="slider"></div>  
                <input class="slider-input" type="text" />
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

I'd like to get a value using code like this:

```
wp.customize('body_font_size_setting', function(value){ 
        value.bind(function(newval){ 
            $('body').css('font-size', newval);
        });
    });
```

but I don't know how to get new value after change efect of slider ui.

I've found customize-controls.js and tried to add lines like these:

```
api.SliderControl = api.Control.extend({
        ready: function() {
            var control = this,
                slider = this.container.find('.nfinity-slider-input');

            slider.val( control.setting() ).slider({
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    control.setting.set( ui.value );
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and it doesn't work also. Nvm, it will be the plugin, so I can't implement nothing in WordPress files. When I try to do the same in my script file I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined.

So my quesion is. How to transmit value from Slider UI to have an acces to them using wp.customize? I think I should to_json() function but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we just need to run the slider using this function (file called: slider-ui.js):

```
(function($){
    var api = wp.customize;

    api.SliderControl = api.Control.extend({ 
        ready: function() {
            var control = this,
                picker = this.container.find('.slider');

            picker.val(control.setting()).slider({
                change: function(event, ui){ 
                    control.setting.set(ui.value);
                }               
            });
        }
    });

    api.controlConstructor['slider'] = api.SliderControl;   
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and load it in our control class using:

```
public function enqueue(){
            wp_enqueue_script('customizer-slider', plugins_url('js/slider-ui.js', __FILE__), array('jquery-ui-slider'), '1.0', true);
            wp_register_style('customizer-slider-styles', plugins_url('css/slider-ui.min.css', __FILE__));  
            wp_enqueue_style('customizer-slider-styles');
        }
```

In this way we can get current slider value by this code:

```
wp.customize('body_font_size_setting', function(value){ 
        value.bind(function(newval){ 
            $('body').css('font-size', newval);
        });
    });
```

I hope it will help somebody, because it took me around two hours to find the solution. :)

Comment: Hi could you explain this line: `api.controlConstructor['slider'] = api.SliderControl;` and the brackets after the line?

Comment: @OhhMee : This line is here to make the bridge between PHP and JavaScript. The customizer API will get the `$type` value of the `WP_Customize_Control` PHP object and look at a constructor with the same name in `api.controlConstructor` JavaScript object. If one is found, it is used to initialize the JS control, else the default constructor is used.